# How to check for words in two excel columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, spreadsheet

I have two columns in my excel sheet. I want to add their output in 3rd column. Formula should check for tags in both columns.
If tag totally miss-matches in both columns output should be shown as "inaccurate" or "failed".
If every tag is matching in columns output should be "accurate".
If some of tags are matching, then output should be "incomplete".
EXAMPLE SHOWN:
[image: Example Shown]

Another Example where i am unable to add incomplete as output. It only checks for inaccurate and accurate.
[image]

Comment: What if the tags are matching but in a different order (will the tags always come in a specific order?), are they considered accurate or not? Also, what if column 1 has 5 tags and only one matches column 2, which has 10 tags? In this case, both columns only have one common tag. The rest are all different. Do you consider them incomplete or inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LET` and `FILTERXML` to test to see if the entire/a partial/no part of the string is in another. For example:

```
=LET(x, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(I1, ",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
y, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(J1, ",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
z, COUNT(MATCH(x,y,0)),
IF(z=MIN(COUNTA(x), COUNTA(y)), "Accurate", IF(z>0, "Partial", "Failed")))
```

[image]

Here we first create a dynamic array of the contents of each cell and call them `x` and `y` respectively. Next, we count the number of matches in each array. Finally, we test this count: if the count is equal to the size of the smallest dynamic array, then all the tags match and we call it "Accurate". Otherwise, if there is any match in the dynamic arrays, we call it "Partial". Finally, if there are no matches, we call it "Failed".

Comment: Its still giving "failed" as output for partial matches.

Comment: Got it, didn't realize that 1) the search went both ways (i.e. correct tags-> submitted tags in addition to the other way around) and 2) each of the categories could have multiple tags. See my edit for an improvement to get you what you want

Comment: It says unknown function let.

Comment: @shahzeb ah, sorry, this will only work for the newest version of excel. Without that version, my guess is this task is pretty dang difficult

Comment: @shahzeb But I saw you post your old answer using ```LET```... was that in google sheets? You can try it there and it might work